# my npm is broken - Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I have visual studio 2017 and wanted to make a Cordova app. I have had many problems with it now and have found a problem. Right now I run windows 10 and have installed nodejs but npm does not work. I have tested with different command but I always get the same mistake. I have canceled Node but I can not drive.
[image]

Comment: Try `npm cache clean`

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this here to help any future wanderers,

In my case the actual issue was due to the presence of a space in my windows user name folder. Which was also clear by looking at the first line of the stack trace,

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\FirstName'
```

Since there is no directory present named `FirstName` and the actual directory was supposed to be `FirstName LastName` its trying to run `mkdir`, for which its getting operation not permitted.

Following is how i fixed it thanks to [citoreek, g8up & gijswijs](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/146#issuecomment-464744140)

run `npm config edit` to edit your config, this will open up a text file in notepad or your configured editor,

then change `cache path` from

```
; cache=C:\Users\Gijs van Dam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

to

```
cache=C:\Users\GIJSVA~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

Remember to remove the `;` at the start,
next question would be how do we know to replace our user name with `GIJSVA~1`?

There are a couple of ways to target this,

1. Go to `C:\Users` open power Shell and execute following command

> cmd /c dir /x

what this does is, list down all the directories in current directory along with their short names which aren't supposed to contain any spaces and normally are 6 characters or less in length. Copy that short name against your user name directory and use this in your cache path.

You will notice these short names only exist for directories either containing spaces or which are longer than 6 characters. (for the rest of the directories their short names  should be same as their directory name)

2. If you don't want to use above command, then simply remove all the spaces from your user name in your cache path, then take the first 6 characters of the user directory name and postfix it with ~1. You should also uppercase it, but it appears not to be making any difference.

After you are done with editing this file, save your changes then try again after closing any active power shell / bash process and reopening them.

Comment: I was having same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my question. I just needed to reboot the windows.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was a permissions problem with the ~/.np* files and directories.  These were owned by root by mistake.  I did

```
sudo find "~/.np*" -exec chown myuser {} \;
```

and that solved it.

Answer (score -2):

base path is specified in the file

[.npmrc](https://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/customizing/the-npmrc-file.html)